# Python Type error: takes 0 positional arguments but 1 positional argument (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Tags: jupyter-notebook, typeerror, librosa

I got a strange problem, last time I ran it, it didn't give any wrong message but this time I ran the code below:

```
x, sr = librosa.load('fyp/MER/Q3/MT0031951901.mp3')
spectral_centroids = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(x,sr=sr)[0]
spectral_centroids.shape
```

It gave me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 spectral_centroids = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(x,sr=sr)[0]
      2 spectral_centroids.shape

TypeError: spectral_centroid() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 positional argument (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given
```

My librosa version is the last one.

Do you guys know how to fix it? Thank you for your help.

It should be running without any problem and I've tried to reinstall the librosa but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem while computing the spectral_centroid of an audio.It worked fine 3-4months ago but now I got the same error. I read the documentation and at first I thought it was a problem of channels of my input audio file, because it says that it supports Multichannel. But then, looking at the example on the documentation, I figured out that you need to specify the input as:

```
>>> x, sr = librosa.load("input.wav")
>>> spec_cent = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=x, sr=sr)
>>> spec_cent
```

Make sure you include the positional argument `y` and `sr`, just as shown

This also works for `spectral_rolloff` , `mfccs` and `chroma_stft`
features. Now it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

as @Derefe said above, all you need is `spectral_centroids = librosa.feature.spectral_centroid(y=x,sr=sr)[0]`. It is so confusing!